# How to increase looping performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, loops, datetime

I'm working on a script that checks if time slices overlap or not.

I have a handler function that looks like this:

```
def intersection_checker(foo, bar):
    if foo == bar:
       return True
    if foo[0] == bar[1] or foo[1] == bar[0]:
       return True
    if bar[0] < (foo[0] or foo[1]) < bar[1]:
       return True
    if foo[0] < (bar[0] or bar[1]) < foo[1]:
       return True
    return False
```

Object `foo` is a tuple of two `datetime.time()` objects:

```
foo = (datetime.strptime('06:30:00','%H:%M:%S').time(), datetime.strptime('08:15:00','%H:%M:%S').time())
```

Object `bar` is a `set()` of foo-like `datetime.time()` objects. That set can include 200+ k of that objects.

The line that calls the handler (`intersection_checker`) looks like this:

```
...
if len(bar) > 1 and True in set(map(intersection_checker, repeat(foo), bar)):
...
```

This code works. The problem is that it takes centuries to process such a large amount of data. I tried using a for loop to iterate trough function, but that didn't work as well as using the built-in map. Perhaps there is a way to transfer and process large amounts of data more efficiently?  Or check intersections in a different way? And yes, it is enough to only find the first `True` value, it is not necessary to loop through the entire bar.

Comment: Detecting overlap is way easier than that.  The only way they DON'T overlap is if `foo[1] < bar[0]` or `foo[0] > bar[1]`.  If neither is true, then the ranges overlap.  Picture a number line.  If 1 ends before 2 starts, or 2 starts after 1 ends, then they don't overlap.

Comment: Must `bar` be a set?

Comment: No, bar can be any type of object. Also, thanks for two upper mentions, i will try both

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely get a boost in performance by replacing this:

```
True in set(map(intersection_checker, repeat(foo), bar))
```

with this:

```
any(map(intersection_checker, repeat(foo), bar))
```

By converting to a set first, you're forcing the entire dataset to be mapped before it can determine if any of the values are `True`. Using `any()` will stop the `map` iterator as soon as a `True` value is found.

Answer (score 0):

Time objects support comparisons, and therefor you can do:

```
def overlap(t1,t2):
    # Check if two time ranges overlap
    # Pass two tuples each with the start and end datetime defining the range
    return False if t1[1]<t2[0] or t1[0]>t2[1] else True
```

Test this:

```
t1= (dt.datetime.strptime('06:30:00','%H:%M:%S').time(), dt.datetime.strptime('08:30:00','%H:%M:%S').time())
t2= (dt.datetime.strptime('08:29:00','%H:%M:%S').time(), dt.datetime.strptime('09:15:00','%H:%M:%S').time())
t3= (dt.datetime.strptime('09:47:00','%H:%M:%S').time(), dt.datetime.strptime('09:33:00','%H:%M:%S').time())

>>> overlap(t1,t2)
True
>>> overlap(t1,t3)
False
```

Then use `next` on an iterator or `any` to break on the first `True`.

```
any(overlap(foo,x) for x in your_sequence)
```

Or,

```
next(((i,f'{x} overlaps {foo}') for i,x in enumerate(your_seq) if overlap(foo,x)==True), (-1, 'no overlaps found'))
```